# Trying to use the "text-align: center;", works on some text, and doesn't on others

Tags: text-align

As the title says I'm trying to use "text-align: center;", but it isn't working on a specific block of text. It works on others, so I'm confused about that. I'm a complete noob lol (have been learning HTML and CSS for about 5 days), and decided to use my knowledge to get an easy 100 on the project. Bear with me, please. It's  that's causing the issue.

CSS:

```
p4 {
text-align: center;
```

}

HTML:

```
<p4>
Over here, we have an economy consisting<br> of mostly fishing, shipbuilding, wheat<br> growing, and fur trapping. There are<br> many different economic opportunities.
</p4>
```

(Sorry, I didn't know what to really put, so you should probably check out the complete code, it's near the bottom: https://codepen.io/fishstick_god_/pen/ZEWjLyX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-align: center` aligns the text to the center of the element, in your case the p4 element isn't the full width of the page so its only centering to the width of the content.  Easy fix is to add `display: block` to your `p4`

Answer (score 0):

p4 isn't a valid HTML tag, so the browser isn't clear how to display it. You should just use p as the tag for all instances of paragraphs. If you want to style one of those paragraphs specifically and differently from the other paragraphs, then also include a class attribute with the tag, like this in the HTML:

```
<p class="special">
```

Then, in the CSS, you create a class selector, like this

```
.special { text-align: center; }
```

You can place that same HTML class on any text-containing tag (like p, h1, li, etc.) and it will center those.
Note that you can't text-align: center; any tags that don't have a default display of block, like an a tag or an img tag. Also, you can't center structural tags (like div, header, nav, etc.) with text-align: center; because, well, they aren't text. There are other choices you can make in the CSS to center those.

Answer (score 0):

`text-align` works on so-called **block level elements**. Like `div` or `p`. See, e.g., https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

`p4` does not qualify. Try plain `p`:

```html
<p style='text-align: center'>Hello World!</p>
```